# Sum multiple rows sq;

Tags: mysql, sql, c

I am trying to sum rows of a table based on one common Column value

```
 ID | cID |tokens 
----|:----|:----
39  |2021 | 2
----|:----|:----
70  | 2240| 1
----|:----|:----
74  |1410 | 5
----|:----|:----
91  | 2427| 31
----|:----|:----
104 | 31  | 12
----|:----|:----
111 | 2432|11
----|:----|:----
369 | 363 | 4
----|:----|:----
370 |363  | 3
----|:----|:----
371 | 363 | 5
----|:----|:----
```

So basically trying to make the bottom 3 rows to add up in the "tokens" column because they share a common "cID" (363) to the smallest "ID" number of them all (369)

Should produce something like this:
(all other rows above)
369 | 363 | 12

This would be initiated by a line of C code (wrong as well)

sprintf(query, "select  min(ID) as ID,   cID,   sum(tokens) as tokens from   char_tokens group by   ID");

Completely messed up in making a table here...

Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're grouping by ID and not cID, is that the whole problem?

Comment: Why the C tag, please?

Comment: That's just an internal counter of how many times the code was ran... can completely be ignored. Important parts are the cID and Tokens.

C tag is cause I need to write this in C and then compile it. and once a command is called that will run the code. -- two part process.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
... group by cID
```

Grouping by ID has no sens since you only have unique ids

Comment: select  min(ID) as ID,   cID,   sum(tokens) as tokens from   char_tokens group by  cID

That does do the sum, to make it 369 - 363 - 12
However that doesnt change the actual table but rather produces a "preview" of what the code does and the table with all the data is still in its original state.

Comment: Cause you haven't done anything to change the actual table. Sql creates those results on runtime. By the way, why do you want to change the values of actual table? If required, create another table to store them.

Comment: @Night - please advise on your desired end results so we can bring this to full resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum tokens on the same cID so just group by the cID and not the ID

`select min(ID) as ID, cID, sum(tokens) as tokens from char_tokens group by cID`

This should work perfectly.